# ant property file overwritten by property task

Tags: ant

I'm trying to set some global properties in an ant project.

```
<property file="env/${deploy.servername}.properties" />
<property name="deploy.username" value="${env.USERNAME}" />
```

As the ant task is being triggered by a jenkins parameterized project `env.USERNAME` is always set but not always correct.

My goal with this design is that if the property `deploy.username` is present in the file at `deploy.servername` the file should set the property and as ant *shouldn't* allow the property to be reset the value at `env.USERNAME` should be ignored.

Unfortunately the value provided by `env.USERNAME` is alway the value used by the script.  Why?  Does ant evaluate `property name=*` before `property file=*`?  Is a property set by `property file=*` mutable?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ant a property once set is immutable by design. There is no specific order when using different mechanisms to create a property - the first declaration of the property wins.
Given propertyfile foo.properties has :

```
JAVA_HOME=some/path
```

Example script

```
<project>

  <property file="foo.properties"/>
  <property name="JAVA_HOME" value="foobar"/>

  <property environment="env"/>
  <property name="JAVA_HOME" value="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>

  <echo>$${JAVA_HOME} => ${JAVA_HOME}</echo>

</project>
```

output

```
[echo] ${JAVA_HOME} => some/path
```

That means the property is already defined somewhere else.
Put in that line :

```
<echo>$${deploy.username} => ${deploy.username}</echo>
```

before :

```
<property file="env/${deploy.servername}.properties"/>
```

to see if the property already exists.